# How to declare values to initialize the state of an array?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I use Flow for typing and always declare the types and then initialize the state with some value, but I'm not getting in the array

```
type State = {
    id_evaluation: string,
    questions: Array<{
        id: number,
        question_content_id: number,
        component: Array<{
            type_desc: string,
            content: string,
        }>,
    }>,
    current_question: number,    
};

class Evaluation extends Component < Props, State > {
    state = {
        id_evaluation: '',
        questions: [
            id: 0,
            question_content_id: 0,
            component: [
            type_desc: '',
            content: '',
            ]
        ],
        current_question: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 0,
    }
```

But the following error appears in all elements within 'questions':

```
[Flow] Unexpected token : [ParseError]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You array declarations are invalid, you have to wrap the inner objects into `{...}`:

```
state = {
    id_evaluation: '',
    questions: [{
        id: 0,
        question_content_id: 0,
        component: [{
          type_desc: '',
          content: '',
        }]
    }],
    current_question: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 0,
}
```

Or, in other words, the types are:

```
type Component = {
  type_desc: string,
  content: string
}

type Question = {
  id: number,
  question_content_id: number,
  component: Array<Component>
}

type State = {
  id_evaluation: string,
  questions: Array<Question>,
  current_question: number,    
};
```

And data are:

```
const component: Component = {
   type_desc: '',
   content: ''
};

const question: Question = {
   id: 0,
   question_content_id: 0,
   component: [component]
};

const state: State = {
   id_evaluation: '',
   questions: [question],
   current_question: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 0
}
```